# Check defragmentation in Aeropsike

Tags: aerospike

We have a 2 node Aerospike cluster with each node currently using ~90G.

I suspect that this is very high than what should have been the actual usage. The Same data is also in Cassandra which is about 30G.

I have checked links like [this](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/defragmentation/718), but i am unable to derive conclusion.

Avail PCT - 74
Free Disk pct - 79

So  this doesn't make sense

> If you suspect defrag is falling behind you can use the following
>   simple formula, 100 - (Avail pct + Free Disk pct). Should this fall
>   between 0 and 20, defrag is keeping up. If this comes in above 30 you
>   might be falling behind and it is time to check the logs.

```
grep "defrag-tot" /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log
Jan 20 2016 13:56:04 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::2088) device /opt/aerospike/data/scm.dat: used 11136, contig-free 20478M (163831 wblocks), swb-free 0, w-q 0 w-tot 0 (0.0/s), defrag-q 0 defrag-tot 1 (0.0/s) defrag-w-tot 0 (0.0/s)
```

Comment: How do you know its using 90G ? Also, your avail pct is pretty good, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: Looks like a doc error, avail pct + *used* disk pct.

Comment: @AnshuPrateek Looking at du -sh of the storage file

Comment: @kporter That would make sense, thanks. works out to a value of 2. Still wondering why so much storage. I know comparing cassandra and Aerospike is like comparing apples and oranges, but for similar data model and same data 30G and 90G is big difference.

Comment: Could you describe the data model?

Comment: @kporter set1 - List or users and attributes - key being list_id,userid and attributes att1,att2,att3.     set 2 same key but large data type - List of all the activities by a user stored per key

Answer (score 1):

@AnshuPrateek question is spot on as usual. You are not going to be able to determine the disk usage from the du command. Your configuration specifies how large this file is, and du is not aware of the amount of that file currently in use.

If you run `asadm -e "info"` you should find the disk used percent which will be the percentage of that file currently in use.

Answer (score 1):

@KedarParikh du command may not show you the actual disk usage used by the server.

$ asmonitor
Monitor>

stat -v used-bytes-disk  gives you actual disk usage node wise on your cluster
stat -v used-bytes-memory gives you memory usage similar to above

Even I surprise the deviation compared to C* and AS.  Are you using any compression in C*?

Your problem looks like my problem too.

Please keep posted if you find any..

Thanks.